# how to make blank last set of string as blank

Tags: r

I have data frame as below

```
col_A              col_A_modified
date/abc/pa         date/abc
date/ab/press       date/ab
date/xyz/temp       date/xyz
```

In the above data frame how to get "col_A_modified"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the `/` followed by zero or more character that are not a `/` (`[^/]*` until the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with a blank (`""`)

```
df1$col_A_modified <- sub("\\/[^/]*$", "", df1$col_A)
df1$col_A_modified
#[1] "date/abc" "date/ab"  "date/xyz"
```